# In React-Native, what exactly does Jest do to be able to test libraries?

Tags: react-native, jestjs

For multiple reasons, I prefer to *not use* Jest. Also, I'm writing React Native with ClojureScript, so the data structures, asserts, etc are all different - that's another reason to no use a JS test library. The problem is that Jest does some kind of "magical compiling" and lots of mocks to be able to run tests.

So the question: what exactly does Jest do? I tried to compile dependencies with Babel with multiple presets - didn't work (one of the errors was `Invariant Violation: Native module cannon be null`). I tried to use mocking libraries like `dl-react-native-mock-render`, and while it *did work* on simple examples, when I added more dependencies it stopped working with errors like a missing dependency like `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault`, etc...

What I am thinking about doing is somewhat make the same steps that Jest do *before* it runs the tests. Does someone knows, exactly, what it does? What are the mocks it adds, etc?

Comment: This question seems quite broad. Really, it sounds like, "How do I reimplement and re-test everything Jest includes instead of leveraging what's already been built?"

Comment: @DonBranson it's more like "how do I not use Jest at all to test react-native", really. At ClojureScript, it'll try to `require(...)` the NPM packages, and this doesn't work with RN because they publish Flow packages. And if I try to pre-compile with Babel, it also fails. 

Jest do some "magic" to pre-compile and mock things, and that's what I want to know what it does.